# Complex Number Equation: $z^2+(1+i)\overline z+4i=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am having a hard time solving this equation. A know the solution from WolframAlpha, but the setp-by-step solution is not available.

$$z^2+(1+i)\,\overline z+4i=0$$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E2%2B(1%2Bi)conj(z)%2B4i%3D0

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What does $z^*$ mean?  Does it just mean $z$?  Does it mean the conjugate $\bar z$?

Comment: Conjugate of $z$.

Comment: Thanks, Check my edit of your post.  I don't think I introduced any errors, but you should check.

Comment: It is correct. Thank you for your edit, LaTex is new for me.

Comment: $z^*$ is the more traditional usage for complex conjugate as $\bar{z}$ might be mis-interpreted as *mean* of $z$.  Both are used, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $z = z_r + i z_i$, and $z^* = z_r - i z_i$ and set up two equations (for the real and for the imaginary) in two variables ($z_r$ and $z_i$).

Comment: I solved it. I knew that I have to use the $z=x+yi$ form, but then I couldn't continue. But I wrote the two equations and then it was easy. Thank you!

Comment: can i use the following concept $x\overline y=\ overline x$ y

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi:  It is unclear what you're asking, but in general $\overline{x} y \neq x \overline{y}$, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$z^2+(1+i)\,\overline z+4i=0$$
$$z:=x+y\cdot i$$

$$(x+y i)^2+(1+i)\,(x-y i)+4i=0$$

$$\dots$$

Answer (score 0):

Where $\Re$ is the real part and $\Im$ is the imaginary part. (So $\Re+\mathrm{i}\Im=z$)

$$(\Re+i\Im)^2+(1+\mathrm{i})(\Re-i\Im)+4\mathrm{i}=0$$

$$(\Re^2-\Im^2+2\mathrm{i}\Re\Im)+(1+\mathrm{i})(\Re-\mathrm{i}\Im)+4\mathrm{i}=0$$

$$(\Re^2-\Im^2+2\mathrm{i}\Re\Im)+(\Re+\Im+\mathrm{i}\Re-\mathrm{i}\Im)+4\mathrm{i}=0$$

$$\Re^2-\Im^2+2\mathrm{i}\Re\Im+\Re+\Im+\mathrm{i}\Re-\mathrm{i}\Im+4\mathrm{i}=0$$

Complex parts are equal:

$$2\Im\Re+\Re-\Im=-4$$

Real parts are equal:

$$\Re^2-\Im^2+\Re+\Im=0$$

Then I couldn't move further. But WolframAlpha could: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2xy+%2Bx-y%3D-4;x%5E2-y%5E2%2Bx%2By%3D0

*Too long for a comment.*

Comment: Worth mentioning: only real values of $x$ and $y$ should be accepted.

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing except that I could see that:
$x^2-y^2+x+y = (x-y+1)(x+y)$

Answer (score 0):

$$z^2+(1+i)\,\bar z+4i=0$$

Let $z=x+iy,\;x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

$$(x+iy)^2+(1+i)(x-iy)+4i=0$$

$$x^2+x-y^2+y+i (2 x y+x-y+4)=0$$
which translates in the system
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x^2+x-y^2+y=0 \\
 2  xy+x-y+4=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Solve the second equation for $y$ we get $y=-\dfrac{x+4}{2 x-1}$

and plug in the first

$$x^2+x-\frac{(x+4)^2}{(2 x-1)^2}-\frac{x+4}{2 x-1}=0$$
from which

$4 x^4-6 x^2-14 x-12=0$

factor $2 (x-2) (x+1) \left(2 x^2+2 x+3\right)=0$

$x_1=2;\;x_2=-1$ and substituting in $y=-\dfrac{x+4}{2 x-1}$

$y_1=-2;\;y_2=1$

So the solutions to the given equation are

$z_1=2-2i;\;z_2=-1+i$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

$z = x+iy\\
z^2 + (1+i)\bar z + 4i = 0\\
x^2 -y^2 + (2xy)i + (x-y) + (x+y)i + 4i = 0$

Separate the real and "imaginary" components

$x^2 -y^2 + (x-y)= 0\\
2xy + x+y + 4= 0$

rotate the plane

$u = x+y\\
v = x-y$

making that substitution into $x^2 -y^2 + (x-y)= 0$ equation.

$uv + v = 0\\
(u+1)v = 0\\
u = -1 \text { or } v=0$

This will be useful

The other equation transforms to

$\frac 12 u^2 - \frac 12 v^2 + u + 4 = 0$

case: $u = -1$

$-\frac 12 v^2 + \frac 72= 0\\
v = \pm \sqrt {7}\\
x = \frac 12 (u+v)\\
y = \frac 12 (u-v)\\
z = -\frac 12 + i\frac {7}{2}, -\frac 12 - i \frac {7}{2}$

case: $v = 0$

$\frac 12 u^2 + u + 4 = 0$

has no real roots and we are requiring $x,y$ to be real.

Answer (score 0):

The following is based on the often useful observation that $(1+i)^2=2i\,$, so the equation can be written as:

$$
z^2+(1+i)\,\overline z+2(1+i)^2=0
$$

Dividing by $(1+i)^2\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
\left(\frac{z}{1+i}\right)^2 + \frac{\bar z}{1+i} \color{red}{\cdot \frac{(1-i)^2}{(1-i)^2}} + 2 = 0 \;\;\iff\;\; \left(\frac{z}{1+i}\right)^2 + \frac{\bar z}{1-i} \cdot \frac{-\bcancel{2}i}{\bcancel{2}} + 2 = 0
$$

With the substitution $\displaystyle\;w = \frac{z}{1+i} \iff \bar w = \frac{\bar z}{1 - i}\,$ the latter can be written as:

$$
w^2 - i\,\bar w + 2 = 0 \tag{1}
$$

Taking conjugates on both sides:

$$
\bar w^2 + i\,w + 2 = 0 \tag{2}
$$

Subtracting $(1)-(2)\,$:

$$
w^2 - \bar w^2 - i\,(w + \bar w) = 0 \;\;\iff\;\;(w+\bar w)(w - \bar w - i)=0 \tag{3}
$$

The factorization $(3)$ leaves two cases to check:

- $\;w-\bar w -i=0 \iff \operatorname{Im}(w) = \frac{1}{2}\,$, so $w = x + \frac{1}{2}i$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}\,$, but substituting back into $(1)$ gives no solutions.
- $\;w+\bar w=0 \iff \operatorname{Re}(w) = 0\,$, so $w=i y$ for some $y \in \mathbb{R}\,$, then $(1)$ gives $-y^2-y+2=0$ with solutions $y = 1, -2$ corresponding to $w = i, -2i$ and $z=(1+i)w=-1+i,2-2i\,$.